# Modify Alfresco Thumbnail Resolution

Tags: alfresco, thumbnails, resolution

I'm using Alfresco Community v5.2.0 to store some files (pdf, jpg/png essentially).
I'm creating a web app to retrieve this files.
I'm trying to create a grid of files from a specific folder in my application.
But when i'm retrieving the list of a specific folders with their thumbnails, the resolution of the thumbnail is very low (100x75).

How to configure Alfresco to generate a larger thumbnail ?

I tried to override the settings in :

> C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\cmisfs\stylesheets\
>   thumbnails.xsl

But this didn't work..

I'm using Alfresco on my computer (windows), with REST API call.
Where can i configure this resolution ?

Thanks in advance,

Julien
Lyon, FR.

Comment: How do you get the thumbnails?

Comment: I use `/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/d149f1c3-022a-4bcb-844e-cac2497aafea/children?include=thumbnail` to get the Tumbnail-id of a PDF.
And then I load the content of the thumbnail by using his id:
`/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/87d63477-f84d-44e4-b6fa-88b8610ba5dc/content`
How can I override the heigth and width for the thumbnail generation ?

Comment: Do you know if it's more reliable to get the doclib thumbnail or the medium thumbnail.
I Found a way to ovveride the thumbnail definition by using a custom file :
[link](https://github.com/surevine/alfresco-repository-client-customisations/blob/master/config/alfresco/thumbnail-service-context.xml)

Comment: But the resolution is still 100x75 :'(

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way to ovveride the thumbnail definition :

I created a file

> thumbnail-service-context.xml

in

> [AlfrescoRootFolder]\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\

In this file I wrote :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <!-- Slingshot Document Library image thumbnail options -->
    <!-- Note that this will auto-register with parent="baseThumbnailDefinition" in the future -->
    <bean id="thumbnailDefinitionDoclib" class="org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailDefinition">
        <property name="name" value="doclib" />
        <property name="mimetype" value="image/png"/>
        <property name="transformationOptions">
            <bean parent="defaultImageTransformationOptions">
                <property name="resizeOptions">
                    <bean parent="defaultImageResizeOptions">
                        <property name="width" value="900"/>
                        <property name="height" value="900"/>
                        <property name="allowEnlargement" value="false" />
                    </bean> 
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="placeHolderResourcePath" value="alfresco/thumbnail/thumbnail_placeholder_doclib.png" />
        <property name="mimeAwarePlaceHolderResourcePath" value="alfresco/thumbnail/thumbnail_placeholder_doclib{0}.png" />
        <property name="runAs" value="System"/>
        <property name="failureHandlingOptions" ref="standardFailureOptions"/>
    </bean>
</beans>`

And now I can retrieve a thumbnail by calling :

> /alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{idDocAlfresco}/renditions/doclib/content